# PhpStorm: code analysis - static calls from class name

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have got a warning in PhpStorm for a common use of static calls.
I have:

```
class Test {
  public static function thisIsATest(){
     // do stuff
  }
}
```

Then, I have:

```
$className = 'Test';
$className::thisIsATest();
```

This is not an error, btw I have this in my PhpStorm:
[image: warning_phpstorm]

Is there a way to handle this? At least, is it possible to just hide this warning?

Comment: How about using PHP 5.3.0 or greater. Before this version, your syntax isnt allowed. Test Versions herer: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: Alternative you can do this: `call_user_func(array('Test','thisIsATest'));`

Comment: Unfortunately PhpStorm does not support such class referencing properly yet. Two options 1) Disable "Unknown method" inspection .. but this will affect all other places as well; 2) Suppress message for this line by placing `/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection */` on a line just before `$className::thisIsATest();` 3) Give a hand to IDE by providing better type hint for `$className` variable -- the one that IDE understands: `/** @var Test $className */` before `$className = 'Test';` line

Comment: Disabling this inspection is not really an option. I hoped that there were a way to tell Phpstorm inspector how to handle this. Using `/** @var ...` is an option, but that bothers me because it's not its really type.

Comment: Afterwards, they introduced this syntax in php5.3 to avoid using `call_user_func ` functions (as far as i know). I'm going to downgrade the severity of this warning for now. Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

There are some solutions, for this problem:

1. change to a PHP Version >= 5.3.0
2. use `call_user_func(array('Test','thisIsATest'));` in older PHP versions
3. change code-inspection-behavior in phpstrom under project settings (also ensure phpstrom has the right PhpVersion set up for your current project)
4. [**Solution**] Declare the variable with annotations in phpstrom in the right way!

Like:

```
  <?php
  /**
   * @var $className Test
   */
  $className::thisIsATest();
```

Now phpstrom know that `$className` is a instance of `Test` that has a method called `thisIsATest`, and no error hint pops up.

Comment: In fact, my code works (i'm on a PHP5.6). It's just the code hilighter of Phpstorm which shows me a  warning. I downgraded the severity for now. Thank's!

Comment: @dam660 Working with Phpstorm feels sometimes like having a million minions around :-)  I have noted a little bit late that your Q was about phpstrom not the code itself. :)

Comment: @dam660 Check my answer again!

Comment: Oh! This works! This syntax is not part of the [documentation](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html). It says : `@var [“Type”] [$element_name] [<description>]`. Your proposal is to switch $element_name with type. What does it really means? Thank you!

Comment: @dam660 I some cases the second argument [$variablename] is optional, so maybe it also detects the first two arguments by itself, so the order isnt  not really relevant. Also your link show the use within a class, but in my case it is used global. And in the end phpstorm does his interpretation. But, as long it worked ... :)